# Signalling a event handler when two particular events have occured

Tags: c#, multithreading, events

My dotnet application handles the following SystemEvents.

Systems.SessionSwitchEvents
Reason : Lock and Unlock

Systems.OnPowerModeChanged 
Modes :  Resume and Suspend

Network events

Now the Resume event triggers 3 events

unlock , resume and some network events ( some times it triggers multiple network events (up/down ) not stabilized)

Now i have a functionality which is all the same for all these events which i have implemented in thier corresponding event handlers.

I want a  sync when a resume event occurs.

basically want to signal the resume event handler when both unlock and network Up events have occured until then the Resume event handler should sleep.

IS there a way to signal my resume event handler when two events occur.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to count your events and block until they have all been triggered. A Countdown type would be appropriate. See this example [Countdown event](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx#_Writing_a_CountdownEvent).